# Constructing a specific regular expression

Tags: java, regex

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexString {

    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.

      String line  = "control.avgo: 29 50.49854 50.504984 50000 50.5000001 0.0 1 2"


      String pattern = "()()()()()()()()";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value group 0: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 1: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 2: " + m.group(2) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 3: " + m.group(3) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 4: " + m.group(4) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 5: " + m.group(5) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 6: " + m.group(6) );
         System.out.println("Found value group 7: " + m.group(7) );

      } else {
         System.out.println("Pattern is no good!");
      }
   }
}
```

Hello everyone!

The above is a simple example I found on regex, what I aim to do is construct a regex pattern to extract each of those numbers integers and doubles and place it within each group. My research so far has only been able to get the integers I have no clue how to extract each of the int's double's and place them into each group?!? I understand the grouping concept hence the ()()()()().... Would it be easier to look at the spaces and extract the numbers within them or can (int)(double)(double)(int)(double)(int)(int) expression be crafted?

Comment: Looks like you're splitting by space.  You probably don't need a regex here.  Try `line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: i am actually quite surprised your pattern does anything. What is the output you get from running the program?

Comment: It outputs with found value blanks on all the groups.

Comment: so... whitespace or empty strings?

Comment: The output exactly is: Found value group 0: control.avgo: 29 50.49854 50.504984 50000 50.5000001 0.0 1
Found value group 1: 
Found value group 2: 
Found value group 3: 
Found value group 4: 
Found value group 5: 
Found value group 6: 
Found value group 7: ...so empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can substitute your `int`s for something like `[0-9]+` and your `double`s for `[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*` and you should be alright, for input similar to the sample one.

```
String pattern = "([0-9]+) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+) *([0-9]+)";
```

**(EDIT)** this worked ok with your input (use groups from 1 to 8 to get the numbers):

```
  String pattern = "([0-9]+) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *([0-9]+) *([0-9]+)";
```

Comment: It has an error within the first group about invalid escape sequences, FYI I'm using Eclipse if that helps.

Comment: The output of group 0: 29 50.49854 50.504984 50000 50.5000001 0.0 1 2 I need it so that its just 29 and so on. =) Aside from that the answer is almost spot on!

Comment: group 0 is always the whole match, no?

Comment: I did not know that ok no worries I'll establish additional groups then!

Comment: Both answers work is it important who gets the green tick? I upvoted both!

Comment: To be more complete, ints should really be `[+-]?[0-9]++` and doubles should really be `[+-]?+[0-9]*+(?:\.[0-9]++)?+(?:[Ee][+-]?[0-9]++)?+`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this: by putting non space characters in each group separated by a space character or a tab character depending on your data format.

```
^\S+\s(\d+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)
```

For your convenience here is the link to test your regular expressions..its quite useful.
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

Does this regular expression work for what you need to do?

```
  String pattern = "([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)";
```

Alternatively, you could split the String using spaces.

```
line.split(" ");
```

Do note that in each of these cases, the value you are getting is a String. You'll need to convert them to integers or doubles using `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble()`.

**EDIT**

To ignore the first section - control.avgo

```
  String pattern = "[^ ]+ ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)";
```

`Matcher.group(0)` specifically matches the entire pattern. So simply don't use it.

Comment: this is the output:Found value group 0: control.avgo: 29 50.49854 50.504984 50000 50.5000001 0.0 1
Found value group 1: control.avgo:
Found value group 2: 29
Found value group 3: 50.49854
Found value group 4: 50.504984
Found value group 5: 50000
Found value group 6: 50.5000001
Found value group 7: 0.0

Comment: Ideally I wanted each group to be specific to a single number if that makes sense?

Comment: Not clear. value group 3 is 50.49854. Similarly Value group 5 is 50000. Are you saying you want the control.avgo to be ignored? Don't look at group 0, as that matches the entire pattern.

Comment: Yes that exactly right I need the regex matcher to ignore the control.avgo basically If I can remove the results of group 0 and 1 and focus only on the numbers that is the exact answer. How do I do that?

Comment: group(0) specifically returns the entire matched area. Just don't call it. Updated my answer for what you need. But you should really just be splitting by space and then starting from index 1. Regex doesn't sound like a good match for what you are doing here.

Comment: Both answers work is it important who gets the green tick I upvoted both!